# Django not responding back to react

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am requesting React frontend to a view in Django (rest framework).
The view in Django will request another server (Google-Ads API), the request works fine and I get the data perfectly. The post-processing of that data also works fine but Django gets stuck after that means It will not run **return Response(data)**.

Django view sample code

```py
def get(self,request):
    data = google_api_request(credentials)
    data = preprocess(data)
    print("end") # this will be executed
    return Response(data,status) # this will not be executed
```

google_api_request code

```py
def google_api_request(credentials):
    data = list()
    # if I remove this for loop it works
    for x in sample_list:
        d = google_ads_request(x)
        data.append(d)
    return data
```

React sample code:

```js
axiosInstance.get("url").then(
    (result) => {
        if (result.status == 200) {
            console.log("success")
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        throw error;
    })
```

When I paste the "URL" directly in my browser it works and returns the Response, but only when I run it from react it does not respond.

When I commented google_api_request() code and load the data from a CSV file in the local machine for debugging It returns the Response.

Note: There is no errors message in the console or Django and my CORS setting is correct as other function works fine.

Edit: I found that issue was making requests inside a for a loop.
When I ran only one request without for loop while debugging it worked. so now the question is how to make multiple requests inside Django using for loop. One important thing to note is this problem is only caused when I call the API using React, things work fine when I paste the URL directly in my browser.

Comment: What is `google_api_request`? Is that a separate function you've defined or is it a member of some package?

Comment: @gmdev yes it is a separate function, that function is used to get data from Google -ads account, that function works perfectly fine when I call it using react.

Comment: If you log the result object in your then ?
Or did the catch match something ?

Comment: @jean-smaug it never reaches there. It stops working at print("end") on the Django side.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `google_api_request` is returning what you expect? Maybe there's a timeout or something similar?

Comment: @gmdev  yes, **google_api_request** is working fine and I am getting the expected data, actually, there are other google functions after google_api_request those functions create ads for my account. Those functions are also working and creating ads. The only issue is **returns Response** is not running when I call the view using react.

Comment: What happens if you print the response in the django view? `resp = Response(data, status); print(resp); return resp`

Comment: Wait. Where is `status` defined? Is that a global variable? You don't have that variable defined in the function you've showed us

Comment: Ok, I found what is the problem, inside google_request_api, there is a for loop which makes multiple requests to the server. If I remove that for loop things work perfectly fine.
So now the question is why the for loop caused this behavior.

Comment: @gmdev no status is not a global variable.  The code shown above is a sort of pseudo-code of what I am doing because I can not show you the whole code as it does not belong to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242988/discussion-between-maunish-dave-and-gmdev).